# Jquery add autofocus to field on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple Modals with forms, I want that when I click on one it will give the attribute `autofocus` to the first `visible` input field. As there are also hidden input fields in the form.

I work with MaterializeCSS to generate the Modals. I have this set up already:

```
$('#modal-entry').modal({
    onOpenEnd: function () {
        alert('The autofocus needs to be added in this line');
    }, // Callback for Modal open
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your alert with this, you of course need the selector for your form or the container containing your form.

- Use [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to avoid focusing on a hidden input.
- Use [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the first input in the selector list of inputs

```js
$('#form input').not(":hidden").first().focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="hidden"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="lastname"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you this works as expected, Perfect explanation!

Comment: @mike no worries, don't forget to mark it as the right answer. Cheers.